# Is there a way to loop XMLHTTPRequest to a array of links that are found from the responseText of the same request method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hyperlink, xmlhttprequest

I am doing XMLHTTPRequest method to get response from page URL. from the responseText,I find all the hyperlinks present and want to iterate the request to the links to find links with status 200 and 400. How can I achieve this with only 1 XMLHTTPRequest .I have used a sample page url. Please advice

```
`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        var x= xhr.responseText;
     var allLinks = $(x).find('a').map( function() {
        return $(this).attr('href');
}).get();
       console.log(allLinks); 
       //iterate the request to the links to find 400 and 200
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'https://reqres.in/', true);
xhr.send(null);`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3oefmxg/14/

Comment: So select the links and loop over them making the calls.....

Comment: It is not possible to: _**find links with status 200 and 400 (for all hyperlinks)**_ with  _**only 1 XMLHTTPRequest.**_

Comment: if that is the case, can you please provide me an alternative solution.I want the list of links with status 200 and 400.